# Reduce size of .apk file when use native libraries in android without using pro-guard

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]I am developing a PDF related application in android (java). For PDF editing and converting others file type to PDF file, I add some native libraries and that work fine for me. But after developing an application, the released .apk file size is above 29 MB. If I apply pro-guard, the .apk size is definitely reduced as 22 MB. But I do not want to apply pro-guard because some functionalities do not work with pro-guard. So how can I reduce the size of my .apk file?

Comment: use bundle instead of apk for release.

Comment: There is not reduce the size of .aab file using android app bundle.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks: Particularly read the box at the top. Apparently Google Play will automatically minify the APKs for you.

Comment: @MehulDhimmar Solved this yet?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya... No, I am trying various ways but I am not success till now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**`SVG images`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources)

> A VectorDrawable is a vector graphic defined in an XML file as a set
>   of points, lines, and curves along with its associated color
>   information. The major advantage of using a vector drawable is image
>   scalability. It can be scaled without loss of display quality, which
>   means the same file is resized for different screen densities without
>   loss of image quality.

Vector objects are much smaller than raster image format. If we have full size image to update, the vector file might only take few kilobytes of space on your system, where the same image in medium resolution bitmap format might not place on CD ROM.

**FYI**

Use [**`app bundle`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) instead of apk.

> Google Play’s new app serving model, called Dynamic Delivery, then
>   uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each
>   user’s device configuration, so they download only the code and
>   resources they need to run your app. You no longer have to build,
>   sign, and manage multiple APKs to support different devices, and users
>   get smaller, more optimized downloads.

Comment: I do all as you mention above. I am having a problem with libraries size, not images.

Comment: @MehulDhimmar read https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Comment: @MehulDhimmar https://medium.com/vectorly/how-we-reduced-our-app-size-by-72-c2471ba75954

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can try is from
 `Refactor`>`Remove Unused Resaurces` it will remove unused classes,images,xml,etc so it will decrease some of your apk size.

**And** one more thing you can do is `shrinkResources` by adding `shrinkResources true`

as below in `build.gradel`

```
android {
    // Other settings

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see his question

Comment: seen he want to reduce size of apk and I'm suggesting the solution.

Comment: `Without proguard`.

Comment: dear above solution is without proguard please check updated answer.

Comment: also you can do this as your app_bundel but by this at some point size will decrease

Comment: @yuvrajsinh, Your answer is to reduce size using pro-guard. but I do not want to add pro-guard.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to reduce apk size. You can start using [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) which splits your app into base, configuration and dynamic feature apks based on architecture(native libs), density & language. When installing, it merges various configuration bundles and create a singular apk for that device using its specs.

This reduces download(install) and update size but final bundle(.aar) file is same as that of universal apk created without bundle.

Another option is to create [Multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits). This way you create and manage apks yourself by specifying  densities, architecture and language you wanna support or ignore. This will be a little bit hectic but this certainly reduces final apk  size as you are only using required resources and libs.

Both of these work in similar way but in case of bundles, you don't have to manage multiple apks yourself. You just handle creation of bundle, and play store will create apks itself depending on device requesting the update or install. But in case of multipole apk, you create all the apks yourself. E.g. If you support 3 languages (en, es, fr), 2 architectures (x86, x86_64) and 
4 densities (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi), you will have to create 3x2x4 apks.